# Pls_integer value requires "less" storage compared to Number. How to verify?

Tags: oracle, plsql

Version :**11.2.0.2.0**

I'd like to verify the follow assertion I'm reading again in the manual:

> The PLS_INTEGER data type has these
>   advantages over the NUMBER data type
>   and NUMBER subtypes:
>
> ```
> PLS_INTEGER values require less storage.
> ```

---

I'm looking for bytes effectively used.

I know the Oracle built-in data types and PL/SQL data types.
I read again the specific sections in the documentation:

[Oracle data types](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17118/sql_elements001.htm#i54330)

[PL/SQL data types](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e17126/datatypes.htm#i10726)

I've reviewed some useful functions:  [visze](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17118/functions233.htm#SQLRF06162), [dump](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17118/functions055.htm#SQLRF00635)(and so on:length,lengthb). 
I've searched here and in others forum/blogs, and even if it seems an obvious thing learnt in the past, I'm a little stuck.

---

My dummy **procedure** (visize function will not show any valid values for pls_integer because the **reason illustrated by Tony Andrews in his answer below** (note 13/07/11)

```
create or replace procedure TestSize
(
    testPlsInteger in pls_integer
   ,testNumber     in number
) is
    sizePlsInteger pls_integer;
    sizeNumber     pls_integer;
    FORMAT_DIM constant pls_integer := 15;
begin
    select vsize(testPlsInteger), vsize(testNumber)
    into   sizePlsInteger, sizeNumber
    from   dual;

    dbms_output.put_line('number:' || rpad(testPlsInteger, FORMAT_DIM)
                        ||' PLS_INTEGER SIZE:' || rpad(sizePlsInteger, FORMAT_DIM) 
                        || ' NUMBER SIZE:' || sizeNumber);
end;
```

**Test**

```
begin
    TestSize(2147483647, 2147483647);
    TestSize(1, 1);
    TestSize(1000000, 1000000);
    TestSize(12345678, 12345678);
end;
```

**Results**

```
number:2147483647      PLS_INTEGER SIZE:6               NUMBER SIZE:6
number:1               PLS_INTEGER SIZE:2               NUMBER SIZE:2
number:1000000         PLS_INTEGER SIZE:2               NUMBER SIZE:2
number:12345678        PLS_INTEGER SIZE:5               NUMBER SIZE:5
```

---

-->>>>>>>>>NEW SECTION ADDED 13/07/2011

Following the documentation:

> ```
> The PLS_INTEGER data type has these advantages over the NUMBER data type and NUMBER subtypes:
> PLS_INTEGER values require less storage.
> ```

and

```
The PLS_INTEGER data type stores signed integers in the range -2,147,483,648 through 2,147,483,647, represented in 32 bits.
```

- Documentation assertion "PLS_INTEGER values require **less** storage **" isn't always true.**

It should be true that number data type should require more space than pls_integer.
Rewriting the previous procedure using a constant for pls_integer size ( 32 bits like the doc says), **we can see below it isn't true**.

I suppose it's due to the **internal representation** of the data type "number"

- But the OP was "**how to verify**"

Using the "**great**" suggestion given by **Tony Andrews**, and loading two different array of different sizes(pls_integer and number), it seems that:

1. Using different numbers that require different/equal storage (output of the previously mentioned procedure "TestSize")
2. Using varray to implement array in pl/sql
3. Testing different dimension for these array 10 000, 100 000
4. **Large arrays of 100 000 numbers require more space** than the pls_integer ones.

**PS** Obviously, this method **is not totally accurate**(like Tony wrote in his post) **and collide with the output of my dummy procedure "TestSize",** providing that the method to calculate the numbers size in "TestSize" (vsize for number) is correct!

FInally,  I rarely use array of more than **100/200 elements** in my production code, just **to avoid to overload PGA.**
And for this dimensions the doubt remains!

Others studies I have to do to discover this "oracle", that is beyond my knowledge; but for this reason I wrote this question!  :-)

---

**Procedure** using the new "Testsize" procedure.

Documentation assertion "PLS_INTEGER values require **less** storage **" isn't always true.**

```
create or replace procedure TestSize
(
   testNumber     in number
) is
    sizeNumber     pls_integer;

    SIZE_PLS_INTEGER constant pls_integer:= 4; -- always 32 bits(4 bytes)
    FORMAT_DIM constant pls_integer := 15;
    FORMAT_MINOR constant varchar2(1) := '<';
    FORMAT_EQUAL constant varchar2(1) := '=';

begin
    select vsize(testNumber)
    into    sizeNumber
    from   dual;

    dbms_output.put_line('number:' || rpad(testNumber, FORMAT_DIM)
                        ||' PLS_INTEGER SIZE:'
                        || case when (SIZE_PLS_INTEGER<sizeNumber) then
                                    rpad(SIZE_PLS_INTEGER, FORMAT_DIM,FORMAT_MINOR)
                                when (SIZE_PLS_INTEGER=sizeNumber) then
                                    rpad(SIZE_PLS_INTEGER, FORMAT_DIM,FORMAT_EQUAL)
                                else rpad(SIZE_PLS_INTEGER, FORMAT_DIM)
                           end
                        || ' NUMBER SIZE:'
                        || case when (sizeNumber<SIZE_PLS_INTEGER) then
                                      rpad(sizeNumber,FORMAT_DIM,FORMAT_MINOR)
                                else  rpad( sizeNumber,FORMAT_DIM)
                           end);
end TestSize;
```

**Test**

```
begin
    TestSize(2147483647);
    TestSize(1);
    TestSize(10);
    TestSize(100);
    TestSize(1000);
    TestSize(1000);
    TestSize(100000);
    TestSize(1000000);
    TestSize(10000000);
    TestSize(10000000);
    TestSize(100000000);
    TestSize(1000000000);
    TestSize(1000000000);
    TestSize(90000000);
    TestSize(9923);
    TestSize(99232);
    TestSize(555555);
    TestSize(12345);
    TestSize(1234);
    TestSize(1000001);
    TestSize(20000000000);
    TestSize(12345678);
    TestSize(12345678);
end;
```

**Results**

```
number:2147483647      PLS_INTEGER SIZE:4<<<<<<<<<<<<<< NUMBER SIZE:6              
number:1               PLS_INTEGER SIZE:4               NUMBER SIZE:2<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
number:10              PLS_INTEGER SIZE:4               NUMBER SIZE:2<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
number:100             PLS_INTEGER SIZE:4               NUMBER SIZE:2<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
number:1000            PLS_INTEGER SIZE:4               NUMBER SIZE:2<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
number:1000            PLS_INTEGER SIZE:4               NUMBER SIZE:2<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
number:100000          PLS_INTEGER SIZE:4               NUMBER SIZE:2<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
number:1000000         PLS_INTEGER SIZE:4               NUMBER SIZE:2<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
number:10000000        PLS_INTEGER SIZE:4               NUMBER SIZE:2<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
number:10000000        PLS_INTEGER SIZE:4               NUMBER SIZE:2<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
number:100000000       PLS_INTEGER SIZE:4               NUMBER SIZE:2<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
number:1000000000      PLS_INTEGER SIZE:4               NUMBER SIZE:2<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
number:1000000000      PLS_INTEGER SIZE:4               NUMBER SIZE:2<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
number:90000000        PLS_INTEGER SIZE:4               NUMBER SIZE:2<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
number:9923            PLS_INTEGER SIZE:4               NUMBER SIZE:3<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
number:99232           PLS_INTEGER SIZE:4============== NUMBER SIZE:4              
number:555555          PLS_INTEGER SIZE:4============== NUMBER SIZE:4              
number:12345           PLS_INTEGER SIZE:4============== NUMBER SIZE:4              
number:1234            PLS_INTEGER SIZE:4               NUMBER SIZE:3<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
number:1000001         PLS_INTEGER SIZE:4<<<<<<<<<<<<<< NUMBER SIZE:5              
number:20000000000     PLS_INTEGER SIZE:4               NUMBER SIZE:2<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
number:12345678        PLS_INTEGER SIZE:4<<<<<<<<<<<<<< NUMBER SIZE:5              
number:12345678        PLS_INTEGER SIZE:4<<<<<<<<<<<<<< NUMBER SIZE:5
```

---

- The OP was "**how to verify**"

Using the "**great**" suggestion given by **Tony Andrews

**Dummy procedure "TestSize2"**

```
create or replace procedure testSize2
(
    testNum       in pls_integer
   ,maxDim        in pls_integer
   ,secondsToWait in pls_integer
) is
    type TPlsIntegers is varray(100000) of pls_integer;
    type TNumbers is varray(100000) of number;
    pls      TPlsIntegers := TPlsIntegers();
    numbers  TNumbers := TNumbers();

    MODULE        constant varchar2(20) := 'TestSize2';
    PLS_ACTION    constant varchar2(20) := 'pls_integer';
    NUMBER_ACTION constant varchar2(20) := 'number';
    SEP           constant varchar2(3) := ' - ';

begin
    dbms_application_info.set_action(action_name => PLS_ACTION||SEP||testNum ||SEP||maxDim);

    pls.extend(maxDim);
    for cont in 1 .. maxDim
    loop
        pls(cont) := testNum;
    end loop;
    dbms_lock.sleep(seconds => secondsToWait);

    -- check pga with query
    dbms_application_info.set_action(action_name => NUMBER_ACTION||SEP||testNum ||SEP||maxDim); 
    numbers.extend(maxDim);
    for cont in 1 .. maxDim
    loop
        numbers(cont) := testNum;
    end loop;

    -- check pga with query
    DBMS_LOCK.sleep(secondsToWait);
end;
```

**Test**

```
declare
    MAX_TO_WAIT constant pls_integer := 3;
    MODULE        constant varchar2(30) := 'testSize2';
begin
    debug.disable;
    dbms_application_info.set_module(MODULE, action_name => '');
    testSize2(testNum => 90000000, secondsToWait => MAX_TO_WAIT, maxDim => 100);
    testSize2(testNum => 90000000, secondsToWait => MAX_TO_WAIT, maxDim => 10000); --10  000
    testSize2(testNum => 90000000, secondsToWait => MAX_TO_WAIT, maxDim => 100000); --100 000    

    testSize2(testNum => 12345, secondsToWait => MAX_TO_WAIT, maxDim => 10000); --10  000    
    testSize2(testNum => 12345, secondsToWait => MAX_TO_WAIT, maxDim => 100000); --100 000

    testSize2(testNum => 2147483647, secondsToWait => MAX_TO_WAIT, maxDim => 100);
    testSize2(testNum => 2147483647, secondsToWait => MAX_TO_WAIT, maxDim => 10000); --10  000
    testSize2(testNum => 2147483647, secondsToWait => MAX_TO_WAIT, maxDim => 100000); --100 000*\*\*/

    dbms_application_info.set_action(action_name => 'END');
end;
```

**Query to monitor PGA**

```
select vsst.sid || ',' || vses.serial# username, vsst.value,vses.MODULE,vses.ACTION
from   v$sesstat vsst, v$statname vstt, v$session vses
where  vstt.statistic# = vsst.statistic#
and    vsst.sid = vses.sid
and    vstt.name = 'session pga memory'
and    vses.username = 'HR'
and    vses.MODULE = 'testSize2'
```

**Annoted Results**

```
                                         pls_integer     number     dif
--                                            size        size      size
--  n=90000000          DIM aRRAY= 100      528612      594148<   DIF= 65536
--  n=90000000          DIM aRRAY= 10000    725220      1118436<  DIF= 393216
--  n=90000000          DIM aRRAY= 100000   2101476     5771492>  DIF= 3670016

--  n=12345             DIM aRRAY= 10000    921828      1380580<  DIF= 458752
--  n=12345             DIM aRRAY= 100000   2101476     5771492>  DIF= 3670016

--  n=2147483647        DIM aRRAY= 100      790756      856292 <  DIF= 65536
--  n=2147483647        DIM aRRAY= 10000    921828      1380580<  DIF= 458752
--  n=2147483647        DIM aRRAY= 100000   2101476     5771492>  DIF= 3670016
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `VSIZE` function will not show any difference because it is an overloaded function that can take a NUMBER, DATE or VARCHAR2 value only (see the spec of `SYS.STANDARD`).  So when you pass it a PLS_INTEGER value that value is implicitly converted to NUMBER first.

The [definition](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e17126/datatypes.htm#i10726) of PLS_INTEGER says

> The PLS_INTEGER data type stores
>   signed integers in the range
>   -2,147,483,648 through 2,147,483,647, represented in 32 bits.

So it is always 32 bits = 4 bytes.  Whereas, as you showed, the VSIZE() of a NUMBER can be more than 4 bytes:

```
SQL> select vsize(2147483647) v from dual;

v
-
6
```

One way you may be able to see a difference is if you run some PL/SQL that populates a large array of NUMBERS in memory, and look at the PGA usage for your session before an after.  Then repeat for PLS_INTEGER.  You could repeat the experiment with small and large values and so on.  (Caveat: PGA is allocated in chunks of a certain size, so this will not be totally accurate, but a large enough array may show any significant difference.)

To monitor PGA usage use a query like:

```
select vsst.sid||','||vses.serial# username,
       vsst.value 
from   v$sesstat vsst, v$statname vstt, v$session vses
where  vstt.statistic# = vsst.statistic#
and vsst.sid = vses.sid 
and    vstt.name = 'session pga memory'
and    vses.username = 'MYUSER';
```

Comment: +1 Thank you. Is there a way to verify the size of a pls_integer or I have to accept the 32 bits without to see it.

Comment: Thank you. Ok I've seen the update, this means that sometime PLS_INTEGER requires more bytes than a NUMBER, like for number 1?

Comment: Yes I think so - see latest update above for an approach to seeing the difference.

Comment: +1 for the new suggestion.

I've followed your approach and I've added a new section at the end of my post. Thank you very much Tony.

I've closed the post.